# iOS app has mysterious UUID with no matching dSYM so cannot symbolicate

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash, dsym

I'm pretty familiar with how crash logs for iOS apps are symbolicated but this one is a head scratcher.

I have MyApp with build 2345 that was released as a beta through TestFlight, using the normal Archive then Upload to App Store flow in Xcode 7.2 (7C68).

When I do a dwarfdump for the binary in the the xcarchive, I get the following:

```
dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: 0BDA6D6F-3C0D-339E-842F-C2CB04199E10 (armv7) MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: B2A69BEC-DF5E-33EA-A9E0-490EBF03074C (arm64) MyApp.app/MyApp
```

Here is the dwarfdump for the dSYM file:

```
dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app.dSYM
UUID: 0BDA6D6F-3C0D-339E-842F-C2CB04199E10 (armv7) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp
UUID: B2A69BEC-DF5E-33EA-A9E0-490EBF03074C (arm64) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp
```

So far, so good.

However, I received a crash through Organize > Crashes for build 2345 that has a different UUID for the binary:

```
0x100054000 - 0x1000fffff myapp arm64  <3715db2438743cf5aac1742d9a214c2c> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7313BC02-3F90-4F94-82E2-CBDC941E5D68/MyApp.app/myapp
0x100144000 - 0x1001e7fff AWSCore arm64  <c2aa13236d0437b98194c0487db69e68> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7313BC02-3F90-4F94-82E2-CBDC941E5D68/blink.app/Frameworks/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore
....
```

I know for sure that the crash report is for the same build, yet the UUID here is `3715db2...` when I am expecting it to be `b2a69bec...`

I do have bitcode enabled so I tried doing a Download dSYMs from the Organizer Archive page (even though I built arm64 so Apple shouldn't have had to) and it retrieved dSYMs for the other UUIDs/binaries in the crash report but nothing for the `myapp` binary.  In fact, the `myapp` binary is the only binary that didn't get a corresponding dSYM downloaded!

So a couple questions:

1. Where did the `3715db2438743cf5aac1742d9a214c2c` version of the
   myapp binary come from?
2. How can I get the dSYM for it so that I can symbolicate the crash?  Apple is not returning it with the "Download dSYMs" option in Xcode.

Comment: Same problem. And looks like it happens with arm64 only

Answer (score 7):

Looks like I found the solution.

It's possible in case you set Bitcode enabled. To get necessary dSym you should either use "Download dSYMs..." button (Xcode / Organizer / Your Archive - right panel with archive information) or download them from iTunes Connect (Activity tab, link in build's details ).

[image: iTunes Connect]

Last option helped in my situation.

Comment: downloaded from iTunesconnect and uploaded .zip file but still showing mussing DSYMs in fabric.io

Comment: @bLacKhoLE it's really strange. 1) check with commands from the question that UUID is correct (dSYM really contains necessary UUID, you can compare them by bundle build and version which isn't enough); 2) in rare cases it takes time (maybe, even hour) before dSYM will be processed and, as far as I remember, you won't see notifications about this (so just wait a bit). In fact, it's 100% I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

2. dSYM stored inside your .xcarchive 
   Right click on archive in organiser then show package content. It should be there.

Comment: I know they are stored in the .xcarchive, but the issue is that no dSYM file there has a matching UUID to the binary in the crash report.  It doesn't show up either when Downloading the dSYM from Apple.

Comment: Sometimes appstoreconnect attributes the incorrect UUIDs. Here is a potential solution for that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820976/1097106