# New Firebase Crashlytics SDK missing dSYM UUID

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I am trying to upgrade **Fabric Crashlytics SDK** to **New Firebase Crashlytics SDK**. I've followed [New Firebase Crashlytics instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios).

The problem is that given Firebase Crashlytics dsym file's UUID does not match with archive dsym files UUIDs. I've downloaded dsyms from Appstore connect(Activity) and it doesn't match too.

After that I decided to upload dsyms with Fastlane. So many dsyms are uploaded but Firebase Crashlytics console still says me to upload missing dsym files.

I tried to upload with Firebase CLI and Fastlane.

I'm busy with that problem since tree days. Somebody can help me ?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Same, apparently they know it on their side, but no solution so far: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5569#issuecomment-689743557

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the fix was uploading the downloaded **`DSYMs`** from Appstore connect using **`Terminal`**

Open your terminal then use the following line (make sure to replace [xxx Path] with the right paths:

```
[Project Path]/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp [Google Service Plist Path]/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios [DSYMs file Path]/appDsyms.zip
```

**Example**

```
/Users/soufian/Desktop/Projects/yourProject/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/soufian/Desktop/Projects/yourProject/yourProjectSubFolder/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/soufian/Downloads/appDsyms.zip
```

Make sure there is a space after `-gsp`, in Firebase documentation there isn't.

Comment: Thanks for reply Soufian, but it doesn't work for me. I'd tried this before. Now I tried again but I uploaded symbols everyting seems great but Firebase Crashlytics still ask me to symbols in Firebase Crashlytics console.

Comment: what is the size of your dSYM ? and do you get any error ( under browser developer console) ?

Comment: The problem is that the required UUID doesn’t match with the local ones, you can check like:

mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <missing ID>"

Comment: Sometimes appstoreconnect attributes incorrect UUIDs for bitcode enabled archives. Here is a solution for that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820976/1097106

Answer (score 0):

Please reach out at 'support@fabric.io' and include your dsym (zip), app bundle id and I can dig into this with you.